# Magento 2 - Checkout. Remove “New Address” button from billing/shipping address with module or theme

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-address, billing-address, magento2.3

I want to disable the "new address" button from checkout page in Magento 2.
Will it be easy with the theme or create a new module?

Magento 2 - Checkout. Remove the “New Address” button from billing/shipping address with module or theme.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) **Override `shipping.html`**

**-> With Custom Theme:**

**Copy `shipping.html` from** `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html`

**to** `app/design/frontend/{vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Checkout/web/template/shipping.html`

**-> With Custom Module:**

**Create requirejs-config.js** `app/code/{Vendor}/{Module}/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js`

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
          'Magento_Checkout/template/shipping.html': 
              'Vendor_Module/template/shipping.html'
        }
  }
};
```

> **2) Now remove following html from `shipping.html`**

```
<!-- Address form pop up -->
<if args="!isFormInline">
    <button type="button"
            class="action action-show-popup"
            click="showFormPopUp"
            visible="!isNewAddressAdded()">
        <span translate="'New Address'" />
    </button>
    <div id="opc-new-shipping-address"
         visible="isFormPopUpVisible()"
         render="shippingFormTemplate" />
</if>
```

> **3) Now run the following commands:**

`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

`php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Comment: i want to hide button if module is enabled? how to check and on which file?

Comment: Do you want to check any other third party module status to hide/show `New Address` button?

Comment: yes. i use third party module. want to check my module is enabled or not.

Comment: Anyone have idea about it?

Comment: Please ask another question and paste the link here in a comment to make this thread clean and clear.

Comment: how to check module enabled or not in above method?

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/253118/magento2-how-to-check-module-enabled-or-not-for-override-html

Comment: @UtsavGupta Please check my answer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/253133/35758

Comment: @PrincePatel, Above code helped to remove New Address button, how to remove new address option from drop down..

Comment: @PrincePatel, How to give link for the button instead of pop up?

Comment: @jafarpinjar Please ask other question for new queries/updates with a link this answer to make this thread clean :)

Comment: @PrincePatel,here is my new question https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/267933/adding-link-to-the-checkout-button-in-magento2

Comment: @PrincePatel i have to move its position please tell how can i do that

Answer (score 1):

For hiding "New address" from billing address step in checkout. We need to override the **billing-address.js** from **vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\js\view\billing-address.js** and comment the below code:

```
addressOptions.push(newAddressOption);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using these codes in **vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\js\view\billing-address.js:**

var lastSelectedBillingAddress = null,

```
countryData = customerData.get('directory-data'),
addressOptions = addressList().filter(function (address) {
    return address.getType() == 'customer-address';
});
```

Now, remove pub/static/frontend/*. Finally, clear the cache. You will find that the "New Address" button has been removed.