# Magento 2 how to check module enabled or not for override html?

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping

How to check module enabled or not for override html?

I have answer to hide "new address" button from checkout page [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252910/magento-2-checkout-remove-new-address-button-from-billing-shipping-address/252914) 
[Magento 2 - Checkout. Remove “New Address” button from billing/shipping address with module or theme](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252910/magento-2-checkout-remove-new-address-button-from-billing-shipping-address/252914)
. I am using first answer, But I need to check  module is  enabled or not. So, from where i can check this?

I have admin configuration where admin can enable/disable module. now i want to check check if this module is enabled or not?

Also it would be website/store wise.

Comment: You can check at *app/etc/config.php*.
Make sure your module is set 1.

Comment: but in which file and how? as i use "requirejs-config.js" and "shipping.html" files. where to check.

Comment: try check at _<magento_root>/app/etc/config.php_. Check your module set 1. Example : _'Magento_Paypal' => 1,_

Comment: thanks. but with code how can i check?

Comment: You can enable magento profiler. (https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/bootstrap/mage-profiler.html)

Comment: I have admin configuration where admin can enable/disable module. now i want to check check if this module is enabled or not?

Comment: You need to override shipping js file to check module status. I will post an answer after testing within a few minutes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

please follow the answer given by @Prince Patel its working.
we just need to change in one file which is shipping.js

**app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping.js**

define([], function (Component) {
    'use strict';

```
return function (Component) {
    return Component.extend({

        initialize: function () {
            this._super();
        },

        checkModuleIsEnable: function () {
            return window.checkoutConfig.modulesStatus;
        }
    });
}
```

});

because we set "modulesStatus" in $config array in getConfig() Function 
@app/code/Vendor/Module/ModuleStatusConfigProvider.php

it will help all.

Thanks again @Prince Patel.

Comment: Sorry, It's a typo mistake in my code but you can update my answer to solve little typo mistake instead of posting a new answer :)

Comment: So @PrincePatel has the correct answer...

Answer (score 2):

**1) Create `di.xml` to add module status value to `window.checkoutConfig`**

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\CompositeConfigProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="configProviders" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="checkout_check_module_status" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\Model\ModuleStatusConfigProvider</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

**2) Create `ModuleStatusConfigProvider.php` to check module is enabled or not and add value in checkout config**

> app/code/Vendor/Module/ModuleStatusConfigProvider.php

Here we get module enable/disable configuration value by `ScopeConfigInterface` and pass it into checkout config

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

use Magento\Checkout\Model\ConfigProviderInterface;

class ModuleStatusConfigProvider implements ConfigProviderInterface
{
    const XML_MODULE_STATUS_PATH = "section/group/field"; //Example: test/general/enable

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    protected $_scopeConfig;

    /**
     * ModuleStatusConfigProvider constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     */
    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig)
    {
        $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

    public function getConfig()
    {
        $config = [];

        $moduleIsEnabled = $this->checkIsModuleEnabled(self::XML_MODULE_STATUS_PATH);
        if($moduleIsEnabled) {
            $config['moduleStatus'] = true;
        } else {
            $config['moduleStatus'] = false;
        }

        return $config;
    }

    public function checkIsModuleEnabled($path)
    {
        return $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
            $path,
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        );
    }
}
```

**3) Now extend `shipping.js` by `mixin` and override `shipping.html` in custom module's `requirejs-config.js`**

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {

            'Magento_Checkout/template/shipping.html':
                'Vendor_Module/template/shipping.html'
        }
    },
    'config': {
        'mixins': {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping': {
                'Vendor_Module/js/view/shipping': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

**4) Create `shipping.js`**

Here I extend main shipping.js and add new function `checkModuleIsEnable()` to check 
module is enabled or not from value `isModulesEnable` with `window.checkoutConfig.isModulesEnable`

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping.js

```
define([], function (Component) {
    'use strict';

    return function (Component) {
        return Component.extend({

            initialize: function () {
                this._super();
            },

            checkModuleIsEnable: function () {
                return window.checkoutConfig.moduleStatus;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

**5) Now in `shipping.html` add knockout if condition to show/hide `New Address` button
based on return value of function `checkModuleIsEnable()`**

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html

```
<!-- Address form pop up -->
<!-- ko if: (checkModuleIsEnable()) -->
    <if args="!isFormInline">
        <button type="button"
                class="action action-show-popup"
                click="showFormPopUp"
                visible="!isNewAddressAdded()">
            <span translate="'New Address'" />
        </button>
        <div id="opc-new-shipping-address"
             visible="isFormPopUpVisible()"
             render="shippingFormTemplate" />
    </if>
<!--/ko-->
```

**6) Remove `var` and `generated` and run following commands:**

```
 php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: is this line correct ?
- return window.checkoutConfig.isModulesEnable;
i used same but still not wokring. its by default disable that button.

used below code

<!-- Address form pop up -->
<!-- ko if: (checkModuleIsEnable()) -->
<!-- ko else: -->
 <if args="!isFormInline">
     <button type="button" class="action action-show-popup" 
 click="showFormPopUp"
 visible="!isNewAddressAdded()">
 <span translate="'New Address'" />
    </button>
    <div id="opc-new-shipping-address"
      visible="isFormPopUpVisible()"
      render="shippingFormTemplate" />
   </if>
<!--/ko-->

Comment: @UtsavGupta Yes it will return value of `$config['modulesStatus']`

Comment: Make sure you changed path `XML_MODULE_STATUS_PAT` from `app/code/Vendor/Module/ModuleStatusConfigProvider.php` per your config path

Comment: yes changed the xml_module_status_path and app/code/vender/module/model/ModuleStatusConfigProvider.php

Comment: no. window.checkoutConfig.isModulesEnable says undefined

Comment: @UtsavGupta It means that the value `$config['modulesStatus']` not set from `ModuleStatusConfigProvider.php`. Please first check the configuration value in `ModuleStatusConfigProvider.php`

Comment: i set path as "setup/status/enabled" from below. is it correct ?
<select id="setup_status_enabled" name="groups[status][fields][enabled][value]" class=" select admin__control-select" data-ui-id="select-groups-status-fields-enabled-value">
<option value="1" selected="selected">Yes</option>
<option value="0">No</option>
</select>

Comment: when i try to print echo "<pre>";print_r($config);die;
i got below :

     window.checkoutConfig = <pre>Array
(
    [modulesStatus] => 1
) 

in console i can get "window.checkoutConfig.modulesStatus" => 1

Comment: @UtsavGupta It means that your module is enabled and `New Address` button will be displayed

Comment: i got true and false value in console. so that i changed the condition as below : 

<if args="!checkModuleIsEnable"> 
or
<!-- ko if: (!checkModuleIsEnable()) -->

i tried both way but it still showing button on both condition.

Comment: Keep `<!-- ko if: (checkModuleIsEnable()) -->`. It will disable the button if `checkModuleIsEnable()` returns `false`.

Comment: How to find out which Magento module is customize/extended in Magento 2?

Answer (score 1):

To know about Module status, run this command from your Bash Shell where you used to run other Magento 2 CLI Commands:

```
php bin/magento module:status
```

And find your module in list of Enabled/Disabled Modules.

You can also enable module from Bash Shell with:

```
php bin/magento module:enable VendorName_ModuleName
```

and Disable as:

```
php bin/magento module:disable VendorName:ModuleName
```

Comment: please refere the question from here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252910/magento-2-checkout-remove-new-address-button-from-billing-shipping-address/252914

Comment: What I understand is you are using third party extension and want to remove “New Address” button from billing/shipping address when module is disabled from configuration ?

Comment: yes, when module is enable button should remove.

Comment: If it is third party extension it should be working fine, more you can extend its functionality by checking its files closely. As per your question the above answer works fine. Please accept my answer it would be helpful for future learners.

Comment: How to find out which Magento module is customize/extended in Magento 2?