# Adding link to the Checkout button in magento2

Tags: magento2, checkout, knockoutjs, shipping-address

I need to add external link to the "New Address" button in checkout.

Found the button html is loading from this file.

> **vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\template\shipping.html**

How can I add external link to the button instead of showing the pop up once it is clicked.

I need to add `anchor (<a>) tag` for it.

Can this be done?

Comment: yes, you can add link using  <a href="#">Test link</a>

Comment: @MohammadFaizan, please update me the Answer, how it can be done?

Comment: @RakeshDonga, some external link with params, params are from magento so href value is formed in php file

Comment: @jafarpinjar i have updated my answer

Comment: @RakeshDonga, yes everything is fine, but it will redirect to which link? where i need to pass href value?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91703/discussion-between-jafar-pinjar-and-rakesh-donga).

Answer (score 1):

try this way...

```
<a data-bind="attr: { href: Link, title: Title }, text: Title">test</a>
```

Comment: hi @Rakesh, already some click action written in default magento, wil it be avoided? above code will redirect to cart page?

Comment: yes i know that but you can use here your link

Comment: yes, @Rakesh, can you please provide me some clear code, i am not worked on ko before, i need to add form href value with some php variables

Comment: you want to anchor tag in which link use?

Comment: I am not understood.. cleared with my question?